# What default mat format version does save use?

Tags: matlab, file, save

In Matlab, when using the [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function, what determines the default mat format version (-v4, -v6, -v7, -v7.3) that is used?

Comment: Did I answer your question, if yes, please mark it as accepted. If not, I will be happy to solve any doubts you have.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Thanks for your answer. That was indeed useful. Ideally I would be interested to have the list of Matlab versions, OSes, and the corresponding default mat format version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the default version for `save`, go to `MATLAB preferences -> General -> MAT files`. I have set it to `MATLAB version 7.3 or later`. If you want to see how to change it, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#btp6quy).

I will just give a short example here for the sake of completeness:

```
a=randn(100,10);
save('saved_a.mat','-v7.3')  %or '-v7, -v6' for example
```

EDIT: I am not sure what is the default MAT-file format for each MATLAB version, since in my R2013b, I had version 7 as the default version. It should have been version 7.3.

However, you can see that since R2006b, version 7.3 was available. Version 7 came out with MATLAB 7 (or R14). Version 6 came out with MATLAB 5. The original version is version 4. You can also find detailed information about MAT-file header etc. in [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf) document.

Comment: Also the default version for save is not always the one selected in MATLAB preferences -> General -> MAT files. On my Win7 machine, v7 is selected but `test = {'Hello', 'world!'; 'Good', 'morning'; 'See', 'you!'};save('data123.mat', 'test')` outputs a v5 mat file.

Comment: Interesting... I get a -v7.3 MAT file when I create the `data123.mat` as you specified: `MATLAB 7.3 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Mon Feb 02 15:17:15 2015 HDF5 schema 1.00 .`